# MVC 3 Common User control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have this requirement on a page when user enters the Zipcode, the system is suppose to prefill the City and State information. I have a service which does the lookup and returns that information. If there are multiple cities which fall under the same zipcode, user should see a dropdown and if only 1 city is returned it should show a textbox. Both the textbox for City/State should be disabled and read only. if the zipcode is not filled or invalid it should handle the error situation. I implemented this using jquery and it works well. Now the issue is they are asking for this functionality on lot of other pages. What's the best way to reuse this functionality? How do I reuse without replicating the same show/hide and other logic on other pages?

In current implementation I have an event attached on the zipcode textbox and it posts to the controller action method and gets all data and pushes back that information to the view through ajax. There is lot of show/hide logic goes around in the jquery

I hope I am clear on what I am asking here.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Implement it as a Child Action or Partial view. The term "User Control" is really only applicable to webforms, not MVC.

As for the javascript, you should somehow modularize it so that it can plug into your other pages -- whether you include the js in your layout, use $.getScript, or whatever.

Definitely need to see code to give a better answer.